# Typo3 - what is the usage of t3lib_div::getUserObj()

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

```
$basket = t3lib_div::getUserObj('&tx_ttproducts_basket');
```

I got an Array of values for `$basket`. Where does this values come from ? How to add new elements into this Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [TYPO3 CMS API](http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_utility_1_1_general_utility.html#a04bd7f695c8bbdf05e91fb4488406473) `getUserObj()` creates a reference to a user defined object. In your case, it should return a reference to a `tx_ttproducts_basket` object, which has been previously instantiated in your code. As `getUserObj()` should return a **reference to an object** (`$basket`), you should be able to use that reference to add more elements to the referenced object.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable information. Can you please explain about how to create 'tx_ttproducts_basket' such a reference.